# How to lower the width and height of the Material datepicker calender in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, angular8

I am using material date picker for calender in Angular 8. 
I am trying to lessen the width and height of the calender because it is very huge and does not suit in my page. Please help out.

The style I applied is below on page and the html:

```
<style>
   .mat-datepicker-content .mat-calendar {
       width: 229px!important;
       height: 300px!important;
   }
</style>    
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" class="modifyDate (click)="picker.open()">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepickertoggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
```

I am unable to do so. My css isn't applying though. 
Note : The above datepicker is inbuilt for Angular 8. Can we even change the styling of inbuilt elements in Angular8. I am a beginner.

Comment: If you write your css in *component style file* it'll not work, you have to write global css or add *encapsulation* in component typescript file.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add ::ng-deep before your style code in order to override default material style:
it will be like that:

```
     ::ng-deep .mat-datepicker-content .mat-calendar {
        width: 229px!important;
        height: 300px!important;
    }
```

Comment: use ViewEncapsulation.None, ::ng-deep is deprecated, https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

Answer (score 0):

Its preferable you only change the width and not height as u won't have to worry about weird behaviors. It adjusts the height with the width.

Since `mat-calendar` uses none view encapsulation, its style can be overridden from any component.

```
.mat-calendar {width:...}
```